# Table wont fit on page since there is no auto line break

Tags: tables, tabularx

I've got a compelx Table like this:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr}
\label{tab:informationen}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llll}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\#}                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\#\#}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Loremipsumdollor}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{3}{*}{PS1}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{PS1.1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt}                                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\ \cline{3-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{PS1.2} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt }                                                                                                 \\ \cline{3-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{PS1.3} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}                            \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{3}{*}{PS2}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{PS2.1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.} \\ \cline{3-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{SP2.2} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}                                            \\ \cline{3-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{SP2.3} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}                                 \\ \hline
                                               &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             &                            &
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

I made it with a online WYSIWYG-Editor for Latex-Table-Creation. My Proble is, that the whole table won't fit in its width on the page. The first colum will almost take the whole space of the page since the including text wont auto-break so the whole table can fit on the page.
Currently it look like this:
[image]

What can I do?

Comment: You're using the `l` columntype (4 such columns) which does not wrap lines. Direct LaTeX usage will suggest to use `X` for `tabularx` columns that should both adapt width and wrap or `p{4cm}` etc. for hard - coded width but wrapping. And welcome to TeX.SE, by the way ;-)

Comment: Do you mean the '\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llll}' -Part

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXXX}` for example...

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same :(

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lp{4cm}XX}` -- how about that?

Comment: of course the result is the same: you override columns style with `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` ... remove all `\multicolumn{1} ...`, which span only one column!

Comment: Although the above comment(s) probably solve your problem, I guess a complete MWE (including loaded packages and document class) would be preferred, since especially with tables there are dozens of packages that could modify LateX's behaviour.

Comment: okay Ive also edited all the multicolumn-commands with 'x' so now it works so far (I don't had to remove the multicolumns even if they a not neccessary). BUT: There are still two problems now: The second column is now shorter but the content is still one long overlapping line. Also the table is now to big in height for the page (okay ist normal but is there a way to auto split it for multiple-pages?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contain much of clutter. I try to remove them and then as result I got a huge table, which can't be fit in one page:

[image]

This probably happen, since i didn't correctly understood purpose of used `multirow`. Anyway, as they was used, the made only troubles with column width. This I can correct, but you need to give use more information (now, when you can see the table, should be more easy to explain, how the table should looks).

My, cleaned code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr}
\label{tab:informationen}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXlX}
    \hline
{\#}    & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet    & \#\#  & Loremipsumdollor        \\ \hline
PS1     & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                                        & PS1.1 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                                                                        \\ \cline{3-4}
    &                                   & PS1.2 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt        
                                                                        \\ \cline{3-4}
    &                                   & PS1.3 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.                            
                                                                        \\ \hline
PS2 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
                                        & PS2.1 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                                                                        \\ \cline{3-4}
    &                                   & SP2.2 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                                                                        \\ \cline{3-4}
    &                                   & SP2.3 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                                                                        \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I don't know, how big is your real text. Maybe you need to consider to use `longtable` or rotate this table, that it will has wider `X` columns.

Comment: Thats looks very good! Maybe I should refrain to use the table-generators in future - do you realy build your tables by hand?

Comment: @MarcM, yes, I clean OP code by hand (of course, this took me quite some time) and yes, all my table I type by hand. By this I have better control over table code. Fortunately, for my use, I rarely use table :)